# Unzip files in multiple subdirectory to one folder in MacOs in beginners terms

Tags: macos

Im new to mac and believe this is what Im looking for from search.  Do I just type this in terminal as is below? Can someone explain step by step for a beginner to mac?

I have 1000 sub folders with multiple zip files in each want to unzip at once to a single folder

find ./ -name *.zip -exec unzip {} \;

What if Im trying to unzip them to a different harddrive location. Where do I put the output location to the other harddrive?

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to type that on your terminal, with those arguments you have to be in the directory the zip files are for it to work. What does it do:

`find` is a commnad that lets you "find" files
the first argument `./` tells find where to start searching, in this case, the current folder, you can tell find to seach into any folder you want by replacing this argument por example `find /Users/me/Documents`
`-name *.zip` tells find which files to look for, in this case any file with a .zip extension, you should use `-iname *.zip` just un case you have files with any case (uppercase or lowercase zip extension), `-exec` tells find that you wanna execute a program for each file it finds, in this case you want to execute te command `unzip`, finally `{}` tells find where to use the file it found as an argument for the program you want to call with exec and `\;` marks the end of the exec command

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} -d ~/zipout/ \;
```

assuming you have a folder called zipout in your home directory.

On your command line, try to do this:

```
$> man unzip
```

You will see its syntax:

```
unzip [-Z] [-cflptTuvz[abjnoqsCDKLMUVWX$/:^]] file[.zip] [file(s) ...]  [-x xfile(s) ...] [-d exdir]
```

See the switch `-d`. That tells unzip where to put your extracted files/folders.

> [-d exdir]
>                 An optional directory to which to extract files.  By default, all files and subdirectories are recreated in the current directory; the -d  option  allows  extraction  in  an
>                 arbitrary  directory  (always assuming one has permission to write to the directory).

So, that's the option I used along with find and exec.

Comment: The above is a great solution, the only thing I missed is an "always say yes" option, so had to repeat hitting the key Y 23 times :)

Comment: @RobertAlexander I don't see that behavior on Sonoma 14.1.1. I extracted multiple zip files using the command and wasn't prompted for a yes/no. It is possible that the same file name may be in different zip files, which may cause the yes/no question for overwriting files. If that's the case, the `-o` flag with unzip will overwrite existing files.